# How to query so that a field of a model will show up instead of the actual model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-queryset

I am trying to query so that the value for a field in each model instance will show up with no duplicates. All of this is happening within the form:

```
class OrganisorClassStatusUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrganisorClassStatusUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['off_day_student'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset= Class.objects.filter(teacher=self.instance.teacher).filter(is_new_set=True).filter(time=self.instance.time).order_by('-date')[:10]
        )
```

Here, `self.instance` is referring to a `Class` model instance I am updating with this form. However, with this code, I would receive a list of `Class` instances for one of the form fields. What I want is a list of `Student` corresponding to each `Class` instances in the form field (there is only one student for each class). Therefore, instead of Class1, Class2, Class3, I would like to have Student1, Student2, Student3. Moreover, if there are any duplicates of a student's name, I would like to show only one. I hope the students are also listed in the order of `-date` for the classes as shown in the above code. Please ask me any questions. Thanks a lot.

Here is the Class Model as some of you have asked:

```
class Class(models.Model):
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('Agent', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    student = models.ForeignKey('Lead', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='student')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case try to generate the queryset from `Lead`/`Student`, and use your existing `Class` filter against the `related_name`:

```
queryset = Lead.objects.filter(
    student__in=Class.objects.filter(
        teacher=self.instance.teacher,
        is_new_set=True,
        time=self.instance.time,
    )[:10]
).order_by('-student__date')
```

If you are using Postgres, you can call distinct with the field name you want, like: `.distinct('name')`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This seems to work, but I get an error when I add `.distinct('name')` that reads `Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field.`. When I just write `distinct()`, the error is gone, but I have multiples of the same student in my form list. Any way I can solve this issue? Everything else seems to work fine such as the students being ordered according to the date of the classes.

Comment: Are you using postgres? And what is the name of the field in the `Lead` model? The issue with multiple students is because of `order_by` and `distinct` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct). So you can try to remove `order_by` and use `distinct` and see if it removes the duplicates, noting that the ordering will be gone.

Comment: I am trying to figure this out for a while. I hope you won't mind if I contact you through the comment section a little later. Your code helped a lot so far.